# Problem with licenses.licx file with TX Text Control in ASP .NET Web Forms project

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, txtextcontrol, licenses.licx

I was searching for controls that my replace MS Word functionallity in my ASP .NET Web Forms website. I found TX Text Control. I implemented it trial version in application, and it works well but for some strange reason license didn't work. I am getting error: System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: The following control could not be licensed. I set up everythink properly, becouse in fresh ASP .NET project this control works without any problem. Other controls which requires license like Progress Telerik works perfectly in this project. I contacted TX support but they could not help me. Maybe someone had similar issue and know the answer for my problem. Or maybe someone know other good control that could replace MS Word functionallity.

Comment: You might want to try installing the [EmptyLicensesLicx](https://github.com/augustoproiete/EmptyLicensesLicx) package which could potentially allow you to build the project successfully. You'll still have to buy the license if this is a commercial control, though.

Comment: Project is building fine, I am getting error when I try to use aspx page that has implemented this control. EmptyLicensesLicx didn't resolve the problem.